# How to replace deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with multiple filters by SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring boot 2.7.0 and want to remove the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I have multiple configs which use one or more (different) filters. I want to update the configs so they don't use the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter anymore like it is done in the official spring docs: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter.

After changing the config (like done in the docs) the filters don't get called anymore.

This is my config now:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/api/path/**")
            .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/ping").permitAll()
            .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/registrations").hasAnyAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER, TestFilter.ROLE_USER_INACTIVE)
            .addFilterAfter(new TestFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Filter example:

```
public class TestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    public static final String ROLE_USER = "TESTUSER";
    public static final String ROLE_USER_INACTIVE = "TESTUSER_INACTIVE";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ... (Internal Logic)

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

How the config turns out after following the docs:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/api/path/**")
            .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/ping").permitAll()
            .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/registrations").hasAnyAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER, TestFilter.ROLE_USER_INACTIVE)
            .addFilterAfter(new TestFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The bean method needs to be `public` and you are missing the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion but it sadly doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Adding the `@EnableWebSecurity` should be enough. If that doesn't fix it I doubt the configuration is even getting picked up.

Comment: The bean method doesn't need to be `public` at all. Can you share what the request looks like? Please add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` file and share the content of the console after the request with us

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation at: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

You need to use the filterChain bean like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .antMatcher("/api/path/**")
        .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/ping").permitAll()
        .regexMatchers(API_BASE_REGEX + "/registrations").hasAnyAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER, TestFilter.ROLE_USER_INACTIVE)
        .addFilterAfter(new TestFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority(TestFilter.ROLE_USER)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        )
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

You can add the ".antMatcher", ".regexMatcher", etc. with the 'authz' call.
Afterwards you can configure login and logout etc. as usual.

Or am I misunderstanding something? After all you posted the same documentation--

Ps: Im new to this formatting, so the code sample might have some problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :D It sadly didn't fix my problems